# Matlab not reading an existing image- memory issue?

Tags: image, matlab, csv, memory

I have a script written in Matlab that reads a set of images in a csv file and does a series of calculations on them. This csv file has 10 lines and 58 columns, each column in a given line has the identifier of the image that will be read by matlab and is present in a known directory.

The code runs ok in parts, but in the fouth line and twenty second column matlab cannot read the image which identifier is in the cell, returning me the following error:

```
 Error in imread (line 369): File
 "/datasets/output_cph_database/copiacolagem/CPHPALL/62/62_post.png" does not exist.
```

This image identifier (62) is also present in the first line and sixth column of my csv file. The code reads the image whose identifier is in this cell without problems. But when the codes reads the file identifier in the fourth line and twenty second column of the csv file it cannot read the same file.

When I do the following command in command line after the error appears it runs ok.

```
a=imread('/datasets/output_cph_database/copiacolagem/CPHPALL/62/62_post.png');
```

My question is: why this error happens? I mean, when I read the image for the first time it is ok, but in the second time matlab can't find it. For each image identifier I read 8 images with the same identifier (the one in copiacolagem folder is the first that I read) and these Images are very big and a lot of variables are used in this source code. Is this issue related to lack of memory? I mean, after I read all images in a given line should I need to clean all variables (or most of them) before I go to the next line?

When the memory used by matlab is full, is it possible to Matlab cannot read an existing image?

Comment: Try `dbstop if error` and let matlab stop at the critical line. Maybe something strange happened like a changed working directory.

Comment: It might also be an issue of unclosed files, what is `numel(fopen('all'))` If every file access is closed this code returns zero all files are closed properly. `arrayfun(@fopen,fopen('all'),'uni',0)` lists all open files.